# Perl subroutine naming conflicts

Tags: perl

How does Perl resolve subroutine naming conflicts when parsing modules in the @INC path?

I'm writing a Perl module and I don't want my subroutine names to conflict with anything that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

This should shed some light here.

Test script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# import 'print_stuff' from TestPackage
# so you can call this sub without package name
use TestPackage qw(print_stuff);

my $string = "whatever";
TestPackage::print_stuff($string);
print_stuff($string);

sub print_stuff {
    my $str = shift;

    print "test.pl: $str\n";
}
```

Test package

```
package TestPackage;
# Export subs, which will enable you to call these
# subs without package name(TestPackage)
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(print_stuff);

sub print_stuff {
    my $str = shift;

    print "TestPackage: $str\n";
}   
1;
```

Output:

```
$ test.pl
TestPackage: whatever
test.pl: whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Use package to build separate namespaces in modules, so you can avoid this kind of problems. The package statement declares the compilation unit as being in the given namespace. [This link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) may helps you.